# How to know the internal pre-processing of automatic machine learning function `Classify`?

Tags: machine-learning

In the [Highly automatic machine learning](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/highly-automated-machine-learning/) page, it is said the function like `Classify` and `Predict` will do things like automatic feature selection, impute missing data etc. How can we know what Mathematica actually do to the data, like what method is used for data imputation, how Mathematica select features etc?

And can we explicit define the method to use for pre-processing the data like imputation and feature selection and clean?

Comment: Don't know how useful it is, but you can always go spelunking:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1742/what-is-the-most-convenient-way-to-read-definitions-of-in-memory-symbols-when-we

Comment: related:[82846](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82846/how-does-mathematica-automatically-choose-which-classifier-method-to-use),
[145](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145/57), [14650](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14650/57).

Comment: also related [How to view ClassifierFunction's preprocessed data](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67159/1364)

Answer (score 4):

If you look into the `ClassifierFunction` object, you can get some idea of what are the pre-processing. Here is an example using MNIST:

```
resource = ResourceObject["MNIST"];
trainingData = ResourceData[resource, "TrainingData"];
data = RandomSample[trainingData, 100];
digit = Classify[data]
```

[image]

This object is an association and has several keys

```
Keys[First@digit]
(* {"Basic", "Input", "Output", "Combiner", "Decision", \
"Models", "Log"} *)
```

The preprocessings are in the input key. The preprocessing procedures are organized as preprocessors and processors. And they will be applied in sequence to the images before sending to the model unit.

```
opts = First@Options[digit];
opts["Input"]
```

[image]

In this example, the preprocessor converts the image into `MLDataset` which is an internal format. We can see what it does by applying the preprocessor to the image:

```
inputPrepro = opts["Input"]["Preprocessor"]
preprocessedInput = inputPrepro@Keys[data]
```

After the data is converted to `MLDataset` by the preprocessor, it will be passed through the processors, which is a sequence of processors. In this example, it contains three processors `ImputeMissing`, `ConformImage` and `ImageExtractNumericalVector`. We can take out the individual processors

```
inputPro = opts["Input"]["Processor"]
{pro1, pro2, pro3} = inputPro[[2]]["Processors"]
```

From the name we can almost guess what they do. But to see what it does exactly to the input image, we can take a single input image and apply them individually

```
pro1@inputPrepro@Keys[data[[1]]]
pro2@pro1@inputPrepro@Keys[data[[1]]]
pro3@pro2@pro1@inputPrepro@Keys[data[[1]]]
```

Comment: Do you know what't the method of `ImageExtractNumericalVector`

Comment: @HyperGroups In this example, it just takes the pixel values in the image and is the same as `Flatten[ImageData[]]`.

Comment: Does it standardize the data? like `ConformImage---ImageToNumericalVector---Standardize`

Comment: @HyperGroups I'm not sure what you mean "standardized". In this example `ImageExtractNumericalVector[img] == Flatten[ImageData[img]]`. But you can always try to test yourself using the example in the answer.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. Now, I think there is no Standardize in ImageExtractNumericalVector. If there is the process workflow information will be  ConformImage---ImageExtractNumericalVector---Standardize